# Quarter Time While Loop

Tags: python, function, time, while-loop, simulation

For my Python text based basketball sim, I am trying to figure out the best way to sim the time for the game.
Currently I have this:

```
time_runoff = random.randrange(10,24)
quarter_clock = quarter_clock - time_runoff
```

After every play, the play_function will subtract a random number, `time_runoff`, from the quarter clock, which is in seconds (12 minute quarters).
My whole loop looks like this:

```
While quarter clock > 0:
play_function()
```

This works ok, but when I run it, the time always ends up to be negative and never really is exactly 12 minute quarters.

I’m am looking for help in trying to run this loop four times to simulate a whole game. When I rerun the sim() function 4 four times, it just resets the score each time.
Also, is there a better way to keep track of the time? Maybe use actual minutes?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `if time_runoff > quarter_clock: time_runoff = quarter_clock`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are finding a random value to subtract instead of just subtracting the time by 1 each time?

Comment: I am subtracting a random number because the plays don’t happen at a constant rate, but vary each time. Each time, the team with possession of the ball has 24 seconds, the shot clock, to score. They can either use it all or use some of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can account for when it gets to or below 0, you set the quarter clock to 0

```
import random
import time

quarter_clock = 12 * 60
while quarter_clock > 0:
    ty_res = time.gmtime(quarter_clock)
    print (time.strftime("%M:%S",ty_res))


    
    time_runoff = random.randrange(10,24)
    quarter_clock = quarter_clock - time_runoff 
    
quarter_clock = 0
ty_res = time.gmtime(quarter_clock)
print (time.strftime("%M:%S",ty_res), ': End of Quarter')
```

**Output:**

```
12:00
11:49
11:27
11:05
10:50
10:34
10:17
10:01
09:42
09:31
09:14
08:58
08:46
08:25
08:13
08:03
07:44
07:21
07:09
06:53
06:30
06:07
05:56
05:34
05:24
05:02
04:39
04:21
04:09
03:46
03:29
03:17
02:56
02:38
02:24
02:03
01:42
01:22
01:03
00:44
00:22
00:11
00:01
00:00 : End of Quarter
```